# Cropping tool after file picker (like the one after you take a picture)

Tags: windows-8, camera, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

When you take a picture with the integrated camera, windows 8 automatically starts a cropping tool. You can enable it with this code:

```
CameraCaptureUI cameraUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
cameraUI.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = true;
```

I need something similar for a picture which is chosen from the file picker. Is there any way to use the same Image-Cropper-Tool in the FilePicker as for the camera or do I have to implement it on my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement on your own. Check out this awesome MSDN sample and another blog post

[How to crop bitmap in a Windows Store app (C#)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWin8AppCropBitmap-52fa1ad7)

[An Image Cropper control for Windows 8 Store apps](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/10/10/An-Image-Cropper-control-for-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx)

Comment: That is an awesome example.  Too bad there isn't a built in control that does that for us.  Thanks for the link!